# How to display plain text in webpage?

Tags: mysql

I have inserted my code in mysql database using text area.

What I have save appears is like this in mysql

```
This is Line 1
<a href="test">test</a>
This lis Line 3
```

Now, my problem is to display the saved "file" to my browser which I am expecting to appear like this.

```
This is Line 1 
<a href="test">test</a>
This lis Line 3
```

Has anyone have some situation like this?

Comment: The same way as you insert a text to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlentities on your output display. You can save html or any code as is in mysql with no special attention. You will need to escape it though so user based input isn't malicious.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
htmlentities("<a href=\"http://www.somewhere.com\">URL</a>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If you run this in php you will display the whole html tag. Likewise, you can spew out results from a mysql query, wrapping the relevant content in htmlentities to achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: nothing special. you can run nl2br() on inner content like this if you need to: htmlentities(nl2br($string), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")

Comment: by the way I am writing in textarea.

Comment: yeah all textarea new lines and such will be \r or \n or some such. Not visibly displayed typically but you should only call nl2br on output... by the way, have you tried any of this? It's pretty simple.